# Sort events by order-process stage, and modify the "entry" field

Tags: javascript

I have a map with the following data

```
let res = new Map();
res.set('2022-10-31', 'nav');
res.set('2022-10-27', 'entry');
res.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/sending', 'sending');
res.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/cancellation', 'cancellation');
res.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/paymentToManager', 'paymentToManager');
```

And I need to sort it in this specific order given below and also I need to change the key value

1. nav
2. paymentToManager
3. cancellation
4. sending
5. entry

so after sorting the values should be like this

```
let output = new Map();
output.set('2022-10-31', 'nav');
output.set('2022-10-27', 'paymentToManager');
output.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/cancellation', 'cancellation');
output.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/sending', 'sending');
output.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/entry', 'entry'); // <-- key & value changed
```

So I coded in this way

```js
let order = new Map();
order.set('nav', 0);
order.set('paymentToManager', 1);
order.set('cancellation', 2);
order.set('sending', 3)
order.set('entry', 4)

let res = new Map();
res.set('2022-10-31', 'nav');
res.set('2022-10-27', 'entry');
res.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/cancellation', 'cancellation');
res.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/sending', 'sending');
res.set('2022-10-27/duplicate/paymentToManager', 'paymentToManager');

let datesColorMap = new Map();

let pg = [...res.entries()]

pg.map(x => {
    x[0] = x[0].indexOf('/')=== -1 ? x[0] : x[0].substring(0, x[0].indexOf('/'))
    return x;
})

pg.sort((a,b) => {
    if(order.get(a[1]) < order.get(b[1])) 
    return -1;
  else if(order.get(a[1]) > order.get(b[1])) 
    return 1;
  else return 0;
})

pg.map(x => {
    checkDuplicateAndSetMap(datesColorMap, x[0], x[1]);
})

function checkDuplicateAndSetMap(datesColorMap, key, value) {
  if (datesColorMap.has(key) && datesColorMap.get(key) !== value)       {
    key = key + `/duplicate/${value}`;
  }
  datesColorMap.set(key, value);
}

let final = [...datesColorMap.entries()];

console.log(final)
```

This gives the expected result. Just wondering whether it can be improved?

Comment: @ggorlen Per [this meta post about adding a snippet](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2525/120114): "_If you do this, please be careful not to run the `Tidy` tool, as indentation and formatting is a topic for review and would be an invalid edit._"

Comment: Good catch--I'm pretty sure I didn't, but I guess Shift+Tab was enough to "fix" a couple of the weird indentations. The tidy tool would have changed `if(` to `if (`  Thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Avoid relying on map ordering

Yes, `Map`s are technically ordered, but it's generally an antipattern to rely on it. Key-value pair structures are designed for lookups, not iteration. The fact that you have to convert it to an array and back shows the awkwardness of trying to use the structure as an ordered collection. If you find you're needing to iterate the map more often than you're using it for lookups, or you're calling `.entries()`, `.values()` or `.keys()` excessively, consider using an array instead.

Be wary of premature optimization. If your data is small, then making `order` a `Map` might be slower and more code to deal with than an `Array#indexOf`, which is plenty fast on an array of less than 10 elements.

Furthermore, if you find you're needing to split and join the keys often, consider a different structure that has these pieces of information separate. For example:

```js
{
  "2022-10-31": ["nav"],
  "2022-10-27": ["entry", "cancellation", "sending", "paymentToManager"]
}
```

or even:

```js
{
  nav: "2022-10-31",
  entry: "2022-10-27",
  cancellation: "2022-10-27",
  sending: "2022-10-27",
  paymentToManager: "2022-10-27",
}
```

But it's difficult to make a recommendation without use case context. Nonetheless, if the consumer of the final data structure is joining strings to build keys, something has gone wrong.

#### Don't abuse `Array#map` for side effects

This is a common mistake. `Array#map`'s intent is to transform an array immutably, returning a new array. `Array#map`'s callback contract is that it doesn't modify any state and simply computes a new value for that slot in the array. Your first `map` callback does return the value, but since the result of the mapping is discarded (incurring pointless allocation and garbage collection), that doesn't do anything. The mutation does the work. If you want to transform the structure in-place, use `forEach`.

The idiomatic way to manipulate arrays in JS use functional-style chained transformations (`filter`/`map`/`reduce`) rather than imperative reassignments and mutations on separate lines. Sometimes, there's a loss of clarity in the compactness and it's useful to break things out a bit, but if the chained transformations are immutable, it's easier to verify correctness.

Unless there's good reason to, make sure each `map`/`reduce`/`filter` call does one transformation/filtering/accumulation operation and pick the appropriate method. If you're building a `Map` from an array while checking that map for duplicates as you go, reduction seems more appropriate than mapping.

#### Other issues

- Always use `const` instead of `let`, unless you really have to reassign the variable, which doesn't apply here.
- Put logic into functions with clear responsibilities instead of letting it loose in the global scope. The one function that was added feels arbitrary. Why was that made into a function but nothing else?
- Ideally, functions have a single responsibilty (no "and" in the name or hidden behavior) and don't mutate state. But your function name is clear and all of its dependencies are parameters which is good. Maybe the function could compute the key and return it for the caller to mutate the map?
- I like to keep my "raw"/hardcoded data as close to JSON primitives as possible (this is usually how the data looks when deserialized). So instead of lots of verbose `Map.put()` calls for the raw data, I'd keep it as an array of pairs and plug it into the `Map` constructor.
- `` key = key + `/duplicate/${value}`; `` should be `` key += `/duplicate/${value}`; ``.
- The `.sort` callback is too complex. `pg.sort((a, b) => order.get(a[1]) - order.get(b[1]));` is all you need.
- Use clear variable names: what does `pg` mean? If you follow the chaining suggestion above, there are fewer variables to have to name. Less application state leads to a lighter cognitive load when reading the code.
- Use destructuring when it adds clarity, often true for pairs/tuples. `([path, status])` (or whatever these mean), `([key, value])` or even `([k, v])` are much clearer than `(x)` and `x[0]` and `x[1]`.
- Style:

  - Use an [autoformatter](https://prettier.io/playground).
  - Use consistent spacing.
  - Always use brackets around blocks.
  - Use space after `if` and `for`.
  - Add a space after each comma in a single-line argument list.

#### Suggested rewrite

This could be sped up a bit by moving the key split into `.reduce`, at the cost of overburdening the `reduce` somewhat.

```js
const createDateColoring = (input, ordering) =>
  [...input.entries()]
    .map(([k, v]) => [k.split("/")[0], v])
    .sort((a, b) => ordering.get(a[1]) - ordering.get(b[1]))
    .reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
      const newK =
        a.has(k) && a.get(k) !== v ? `${k}/duplicate/${v}` : k;
      a.set(newK, v);
      return a;
    }, new Map());

const input = new Map([
  ["2022-10-31", "nav"],
  ["2022-10-27", "entry"],
  ["2022-10-27/duplicate/cancellation", "cancellation"],
  ["2022-10-27/duplicate/sending", "sending"],
  ["2022-10-27/duplicate/paymentToManager", "paymentToManager"],
]);
const states = [
  "nav",
  "paymentToManager",
  "cancellation",
  "sending",
  "entry",
];
const ordering = new Map(states.map((e, i) => [e, i]));
console.log([...createDateColoring(input, ordering)]);
```